# How to prevent the[' '] when I split the dataURI

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to decode the dataURI to Image. I use split() to cut the "data:image/png;base64,",but it will let my variable cannot be decoded

```js
function Image_Build() {
  var data_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10DY3Qlw6EwC_NnxSxoU-0H88PYKv83rOaRImn4yubDc').getSheetByName('表單回應 1');
  var data_col = data_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data_row = data_sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = data_sheet.getRange(1,1,data_row,data_col);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var datauri = values[1][16];

  console.log(datauri);

  datauri = datauri.split("data:image/png;base64,")

  console.log(datauri);

  datauri = Utilities.newBlob(datauri);

  dataurl = Utilities.base64Decode(dataurl);

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yECMj1EvBQhV1gigslYJu5KM3bxsK9yy");

  var img;

  folder.createFile("test", datauri, 'image/png');
  

}
```

.

Is anyone know how to do?[image]

Comment: Where is `dataurl = Utilities.base64Decode(dataurl);` defined in this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the message is that `split()` returns an array with multiple strings using the delimiter that you defined, so after `datauri = datauri.split("data:image/png;base64,")`, the result is an array like this:

```
['', '<yourbase64string>']
```

So when trying to create the Blob you have to use `datauri[1]`. Also, after that you mistyped `datauri` as `dataurl` when trying to use `base64Decode`, which you also need to fix. And also remember to use `base64Decode` before creating the blob, not after.

Even after fixing that I had some issues while testing to convert a dataURI. It turns out that [`createFile(name, content, mimeType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfilename,-content,-mimetype), is supposed to take a string as `content`, not a blob. Instead you have to use [`createFile(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob).

The difference is just the number of parameters that you need to use, but that also means that you'll have to specify the mimeType and filename when using `newBlob()`. Here's a sample I built based on your current code that was able to successfully convert a dataURI string:

```js
function Image_Build() {
  var data_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10DY3Qlw6EwC_NnxSxoU-0H88PYKv83rOaRImn4yubDc').getSheetByName('表單回應 1');
  var data_col = data_sheet.getLastColumn();
  var data_row = data_sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = data_sheet.getRange(1,1,data_row,data_col);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var datauri = values[1][16];

  datauri = datauri.split("data:image/png;base64,")
   
  datauri = Utilities.base64Decode(datauri[1]); //use datauri[1] because [0] is a blank string
  
  datauri = Utilities.newBlob(datauri, 'image/png', 'test.png'); //define the name and mymetype when creating the blob

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yECMj1EvBQhV1gigslYJu5KM3bxsK9yy");

  folder.createFile(datauri);
}
```